# How to echo a message when mysql query returns null/no rows

Tags: php, mysql

```
$UserId = $_GET['UserId'];
        $UserData = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ElectionBlacklist WHERE UserId=".$UserId) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
            while ($row = $UserData->fetch_array()) {
                if (is_null($row[UserId])) {
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'UserId'    =>  'nil',
                        )
                    );
                } elseif ($row[UserId] == $UserId) {
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'UserId'    =>  $row[UserId],
                        )
                    );
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array(
                        'UserId'    =>  'nil',
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
```

I am attempting to return the UserID = > nil if the query does not return anything, HOWEVER, when testing the page is just blank meaning nothing is being returned...

Comment: Your `while` never enters its loop if no results are found. Secondly `query()` returns a boolean, it does so for a reason.

Comment: `$con` or `$mysqli`, which one is it? One of those is failing you and no idea which variable is used to connect with, including the api to connect with.

Comment: in any case; you have answers, ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so try? Do not send your query

```
$UserId = $_GET['UserId'];
if ($_GET['UserId']) { 
  $UserData = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ElectionBlacklist WHERE   UserId=".$UserId) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
  while ($row = $UserData->fetch_array()) {
    if (is_null($row[UserId])) {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'UserId'    =>  'nil',
      ));
    } elseif ($row[UserId] == $UserId) {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'UserId'    =>  $row[UserId],
      ));
    } else {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'UserId'    =>  'nil',
      ));
    }
  }
} else {
   echo json_encode(array('UserId' => 'nil'))
}
```

Comment: And as I said in a comment, the while loop is never entered if `fetch_array()` returns `false` so this will not work.

Comment: @Xorifelse I meant to wrap in `if`

Answer (score 0):

Then your code is no entering the `while` loop...

You must check your `row` var first:

```
$UserData = $con->query("SELECT * FROM ElectionBlacklist WHERE UserId=".$UserId) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);

$row = $UserData->fetch_array();
if(empty($row))
{
    echo json_encode(array(
       'UserId'    =>  'nil',
    ));
}
else {
    do{
        if (is_null($row[UserId])) {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'UserId'    =>  'nil',
                    )
                );
            } elseif ($row[UserId] == $UserId) {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'UserId'    =>  $row[UserId],
                    )
                );
            } else {
                echo json_encode(array(
                    'UserId'    =>  'nil',
                    )
                );
            }
    } while($row = $UserData->fetch_array()) 
}
```